# NSMutableString is null - what's wrong with this code

Tags: objective-c

Newbie question...
Can someone pls tell me why the value of 'score' is null? What is wrong and what don't I understand? I'm trying to set a UILabel text to the 'score'

```
MSMutableString *score
[score appendFormat:@"Score : %@,[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",19.5]
   RoundNumberFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",19.5]]];

NSLog(@"%f",score)    <-- WHY IS THIS NIL?
```

Then the UILabel is 'blank'

thx in advance

Comment: did you build your code? It's error code. Please check code before commit code on forum.

Comment: [score appendFormat:@"Score : %@",[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",19.5]
   RoundNumberFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",19.5]]];

Answer (score -2):

init score var before - score = [NSMutableString string]